# Unable to pass 1st activity's textview value to 2nd activity's textview through getIntent()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, textview

I am trying to pass textview value between different activities, here is my code that i've tried:

LoginActivity.java

```
    public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

Button btnLogin;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());



    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SliderMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                // login user
                checkLogin(email, password);
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });

}

/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, Urls.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
     //Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {

                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("admin_id");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String password = user.getString("password");

                    //Log.v("level--", jObj.getString("level"));
                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);
                    textView.setText(jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("level"));

                    int a = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, StudentActivity.class);
                    Bundle b=new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("level", a);
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Intent ii = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, StudentActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("level", a);
                    startActivity(ii.putExtras(bundle));

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, password);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SliderMenu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }
    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

StudentActivity.java

```
    public class StudentActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_STUDENT = "result";
private static final String TAG_GR_NUM = "gr_num";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("level")));;

    String a = getIntent().getStringExtra("level");
    textView.setText(a);

    studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new GetStudents().execute();
}
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetStudents extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(StudentActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/fetchdata.php", ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_STUDENT);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    //JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String gr_num = c.getString(TAG_GR_NUM);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> studnt = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    studnt.put(TAG_GR_NUM, gr_num);
                    studnt.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    studentList.add(studnt);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                StudentActivity.this, studentList, R.layout.list_items, new String[] { TAG_GR_NUM, TAG_NAME },
                new int[] {  R.id.gr_num ,R.id.name });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
 }
```

I dont know whats wrong with code but log is showing that in LoginActivity String a is getting textview value, but StudentActivity String a is not getting value from previous activity.. Any help would be truely appreciated...

Updated: Finally i just change my code for passing value from getIntent() method to shared preferences, now its passing data like a charm :) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055702/how-to-pass-extra-intent-to-two-activities) is the link..

Comment: when are you calling this getIntent() method?

Comment: on StudentActivity.java 's onCreate() method

Comment: You don't need to use `String.valueOf()`. Try just `textView.setText(a)`

Comment: @DavidWasser yeah i know it ll work with String.valueOf(), but em just getting the value what it have.

Comment: Can you post onCreate method of studentActivity

Comment: What is the value of `a` after the call to `getStringExtra()`?

Comment: Generally, there is nothing wrong with this code. It should work. There's something else funky going on here.

Comment: @DavidWasser yeah exactly.. sumthing is there which is getting the problem.. a is giving null evrytime

Comment: @Raghavendra here is my onCreate()

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //Getting value of Level from LoginActivity
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String a = i.getStringExtra("level");
        Log.d("TAG1", String.valueOf(a));
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(a));

        studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new GetStudents().execute();
         }

Comment: @Princes Aish your onCreate() is fine I ran your code am getting value for a. Can you post Both activities? Don't post it in comments just update your question.

Comment: @Raghavendra i've edited the activities.. Check!

Comment: @Princes Aish can you try one thing change ListActivity to Activity in StudentActivity and try.

Comment: It is giving another error which cannot be resolved... :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using getExtras()....

```
    Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();
    String a = i.getStringExtra("level");
    Log.d("TAG1", String.valueOf(a));
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

Comment: It is changing Intent to Bundle, em just trying to get the intent, not using bundle..

Comment: This code is broken. Also, using `getExtras()` isn't really any different than what OP is already doing.

Comment: Your code throwing error on getStringExtras() method on 2nd line

Answer (score 0):

```
 String a = getIntent().getExtras().getString("level");
 textView.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

Comment: This isn't any different to what OP is already doing. `getStringExtra()` does exactly the same thing as `getExtras().getString()`.

Comment: check if(a != null){ textView.setText(String.valueOf(a)); }

Answer (score 0):

Activity 1:

```
 Intent ii = new Intent(this, ShareOnFacebook.class);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", facebookMessage);
startActivity(ii.putExtras(bundle))

Activity2:
String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("message"); 
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_resource_textview);    
txtView.setText(message);
```

Comment: Try this@Princes Aish

Comment: your textview value string right you shoudld directly pass your string instead of this String a = textView.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

you are passing bundle in the intent and retrieving intent extra. Either you pass bundle and retrieve bundle or pass intent extra and retrieve the same.
In you code while calling the StudentActivity try below code. i.e

```
  Intent ii = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, StudentActivity.class);
  ii.putExtra("level", a);         
  startActivity(ii);
```

Comment: while setting the text to text view jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("level"); check that are u getting some value or blank.Or just check with passing hardcode value

Comment: Its parsing my json value from mysql.. not blank

Comment: Also my Login activity getting the value, just not passing it to another activity