# Number formatting does not take into account locale settings. Consider using String.format instead android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, string.format

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034899/unable-to-pass-1st-activitys-textview-value-to-2nd-activitys-textview-through) is my question and its solution regarding this problem..

Em trying to pass textview value between different activities, and em getting a problem. when i execute the code, the app crashes on opening StudentActivity, but then it shows the correct result..here is the code

LoginActivity.java

```
    int a = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, StudentActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("level", a);
    startActivity(i);
```

StudentActivity.java

```
      textView.setText(Integer.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("level")));
```

IN studentActivity, Integer.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("level")) => this line says Number formatting does not take into account locale settings. Consider using String.format instead.Please suggest some code..
Any help would be truely appreciated!!

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
textView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", your_int));
```

The correct locale will automatically be used

Answer (score 10):

Regarding the warning :

"Number formatting does not take into account locale settings. Consider using String.format instead android studio",

This is a Lint warning called "TextView Internationalization" which says :

> When calling TextView#setText * Never call Number#toString() to format
>   numbers; it will not handle fraction separators and locale-specific
>   digits properly. Consider using String#format with proper format
>   specifications (%d or %f) instead.

So you should have written :

```
 textView.setText(String.format("%d", getIntent().getExtras().getInt("level"))));
```

Comment: well you still didn't set locale here, no difference

Comment: You can call `String.format(Locale.getDefaultLocale(), "%d", getIntent().getExtras().getInt("level")))` and locale is added

Answer (score 1):

In you `LoginActivity`, you insert String! named "a" into Intent.

In your `StudentActivity`, you try to grab Integer!! thanks for call `getInt()`.

Simply change whole line to

```
textView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("level"));
```

Comment: Hmm I've anyway never used such call over getExtras(). You may try use this getIntent().getStringExtra(). From source code it looks that result is almost same, but getExtras() always create a new instance of Bundle object, so it is also unneeded creating of objects. Anyway your code looks completely correctly and I have no idea why it should complain about locale when you play with integer number. Suggest to check different places in your code.

Comment: Sorry for a delay. Anyway you gave so little details. Generally, there is no place where should NullPointerException happen. 'getIntent' should be always non-null. GetStringExtra may return null, but such value set to TextView is valid! So please check your code, because problem is not on this line of code. Otherwise you have to post longer version of your code.

Comment: i've changed my format, i've used shared preference for passing data

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
textView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("level"));
```

but it still has some warning;
when I use this:

```
textView.setText(Locale.getDefault(), getIntent().getExtras().getString("level"));
```

it is Ok;